# Electron. How to cover the dock panel with a new BrowserWindow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have the following problem. I need to cover the dock panel (bottom panel) on mac os with a new browserWindow - like photos in telegram messanger. The new window should be spread on the whole screen but not in fullscreen mode, because the fullscreen mode opens the new display on mac os.

```
var  {width, height} = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
var win = new BrowserWindow({
 width: width, height: height, transparent: true, frame: false, alwaysOnTop: true
});
 win.setMenu(null);
```

alwaysOnTop - doesn`t work.

Thank you.
Example:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You might want to separate your browser windows into parent and child windows.

It should look like this:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let top = new BrowserWindow()
let child = new BrowserWindow({parent: top})
child.show()
top.show()
```

This should prevent the fullscreen mode when the child window is on top of the parent window.

I hope this helps. You can check out these resources for more details.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-window

Comment: Thank you, I've read the docs, but the problem is not to cover the other window, I need to cover the dock panel of the os.